# SugarCRM portal installation Allow Call Time Pass Reference

Tags: installation, portal, sugarcrm, php-ini

I am installing SugarCRM Portal on my local host. In installation wizard it says that I must turn on Allow Call Time Pass Reference and I did at php.ini and stopped my apache server. When I started it back again an error occurred saying there was a fatal error.

Here is the error on my logs

> "Fatal error:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer
>   available in PHP"

I cannot continue my installation if all settings are all green. This is the only thing that is blocking me. Help Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it

air4x's comment is correct but not detailed so I am here to give the detailed one.

All you have to do is go to sugarportal_dir/install/ then open checkSystem.php. There is a if statement that looks like this.

```
   if('0' == ini_get('allow_call_time_pass_reference')) {

   }
```

All you have to do is change 0 to 1:

```
   if('1' == ini_get('allow_call_time_pass_reference')) {

   }
```

That's it. Hope that helps others. And thanks for the reply air4x your logic is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the PHP documentation that this configuration option has been removed from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

If your php version is above PHP 5.4.0, try downgrading PHP.

Comment: Yes thats true, but i cannot continue the installation of the sugarcrm Portal. How do I skip this to continue the installation?

Comment: I don't have SugarCRM Portal, so can't give the exact fix. But you can use 'find'+'grep' if on linux or an editor like notepad++ if on windows, to search all the files for the word 'allow_call_time_pass_reference', and comment or return true for the 'if condition' likely to be present. Also remove the directive from php.ini.